# g++ Attach a library to application

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, g++

Ok so I made a linux application with the help of Poco library.

I successfully compiled it with eclipse, but when someone attempts to run the application it requires for them to have Poco library installed.

Is it possible to somehow attach the library to my application so that other people wouldn't have to install the library if they wanted to use my application?

I am new to linux c++ programming.

Comment: See if this Poco library has a static library option? In which case you can statically link it. But this will mean the size of your executable will increase depending on how big this static library is. The other option is to package the dynamic library along with your application or make it a dependency of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The current release is 1.4.2. The POCO C++ Libraries are open source software, released under the Boost Software License.

You can download the source from [their site](http://pocoproject.org/download/index.html) and compile it along with your project that way the user will not need the dynamic library on their machine.